# onLoadComplete never gets called when constructing a soondPool class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a class to play back sound so I do not have to re-write the code.

The code was working when it was part of the activity class.

Now the `nLoadComplete` does not get called, which will play a test sound.

code

```
public class cSound {
    Activity Parent;
    SoundPool soundPool;
    int sampleId=0;
    boolean loaded=false;
    static int iSoundIdList[];
    int nLastSound=-1;


static public String[] mNames=
    { 
    "sounda",
    "sounda",

    };          



public cSound(Activity inParent)
{

    Parent=inParent;
    iSoundIdList = new int[mNames.length];

    int i1=mNames.length;
    for(int i=0; i<mNames.length; i++)
    {       
        iSoundIdList[i]=0;
    }


        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
        int status) {
        loaded = true; // NEVER GETS HEAR
        StartSound(0 );
        //StartSound();
        }
        });        


}
```